# Unable to get Joomla fieldparams as array or object

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I would get Joomla custom fields values from a PHP script. I include all necessary files and I can read checkbox values from "fields" table, the "fieldparams" column.
If I execute this code

```
$query = "select #__fields.fieldparams from   #__fields where  #__fields.id = 19";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadRowList();
foreach ($result as $value) {
echo gettype($value); // 01
echo $value[0]; // 02
$var = json_encode($value[0]);
echo gettype($var); // 03
}
```

the type of $value is "Array" (step 01), so if I access to $value[0] the result (step 02) is the global list (so I suppose this is an Array with 1 element)

```
{
"options":{
"options0":{"name":"type1","value":"1"},
"options1":{"name":"type2","value":"2"},
"options2":{"name":"type3","value":"3"},
"options3":{"name":"type4","value":"4"},
"options4":{"name":"type5","value":"5"}
}
}
```

but when I try to use json_encode the result (step 03) is a string.
In this way I can't access to keys and relative values.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here. 1. You're using ->loadRowList() which is a method designed to return an array of rows (i.e. multiple rows), not one as is implied by your **where** clause, and 2. Rather than using PHP's native functions, try using Joomla's JRegistry class instead.

To address these points:

1 Since you're only expecting 1 row to be returned (field with ID 19), replace your line:

```
$result = $db->loadRowList();
```

with

```
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

*$result* will contain the *fieldparams* column **only**.

2 Create an instance of the JRegistry class so we can access the key => value pairs:

```
// new registry
$registry = new JRegistry();
$registry->loadString($result); // load the string from the db

// if you need an array, use jregistry's toArray method
$arrayData = $registry->toArray();
```

Hope it helps,

Gez